# What does the setting queue at Laravel 5.5 config/queue.php do?

Tags: laravel, redis, queue

What does the 'queue' => 'default' setting do at config/queue.php?
It seems like it does not affect anything.

In config/queue.php my queue configuration is **ga-fetcher-queue**.
This is my config:

```
return [
    'default' => 'redis',
    'connections' => [
        'redis' => [
            'driver' => 'redis',
            'connection' => 'default',
            'queue' => 'ga-fetcher-queue',
            'retry_after' => 360,
        ],
    ],
    'failed' => []
];
```

My redis config at config/database.php is this:

```
    'redis' => [
    'client' => 'predis',
    'default' => [
        'host' => env('REDIS_HOST', '127.0.0.1'),
        'password' => env('REDIS_PASSWORD', null),
        'port' => env('REDIS_PORT', 6379),
        'database' => 0,
    ],
]
```

Comment: You have to specify: `'default' => 'redis',` if you want redis.

Comment: @ljubadr This configuration currently works, however, I am asking about the line which is: 'queue' => 'ga-fetcher-queue', What does this setting do?

Comment: From [Driver Prerequisites](https://laravel.com/docs/5.5/queues#driver-prerequisites), redis - If your Redis queue connection uses a Redis Cluster, your queue names must contain a key hash tag. [Keys hash tags](https://redis.io/topics/cluster-spec#keys-hash-tags)